# Masking password in Tosca TCD

Tags: tosca

I am trying to find a way to mask test data in Tricentis Tosca like a password, for instance. I see in TestCases section I can mask data by setting type as Password from string - however in TestCaseDesign there is no such option. Please let me know if you have any solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tricentis intends passwords to be stored in ReusableTestStepBlocks and then use conditions to switch which RTSB gets used for the sign on.  You can store the desired user name in the red section (TCD), and then use switching logic to launch the RSTB that corresponds to that user and contains their password.

This is probably safer, since the password is stored hidden, and intimately tied to the module, so that it's more difficult to "extract" that hidden password data (i.e. tricking Tosca into typing it into a notepad)

This is how we do it in my team.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have them in TCP (Test Configuration Parameter). See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVqvi.png)